# How to properly internationalize a Sinatra page?

Tags: ruby, internationalization, sinatra

I have a Sinatra [route file](https://github.com/dpisarenko/50web/blob/songcontest1/routes/songcontest.rb), which displays some [page](https://github.com/dpisarenko/50web/blob/songcontest1/views/songcontest/home.erb).

```
<h2>Free, open song contest</h2>
<h3>Sign up</h3>
<form action="/signup" method="post">
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your e-mail"><br/>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br/>
    Repeat password: <input type="password" name="password2"><br/>
    Account type: <input type="radio" checked="true" name="type" value="fan">Fan
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="musician">Musician
</form>
<h3>Log in</h3>
<form action="/login" method="post">
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your e-mail"><br/>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br/>
</form>
```

If I wanted to internationalize all string in this page (*Free, open song contest*, *Sign up*, *E-mail* etc.), what is the correct way to do this?

I found this [i18n recipe](http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/development/i18n), but it doesn't tell, how to insert the internationalized strings into the template ([home.erb](https://github.com/dpisarenko/50web/blob/songcontest1/views/songcontest/home.erb) in the above example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the same [documentation](http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/development/i18n) page, it later says:

> Selection of localized strings/objects is easy as it only requires use
>   of standard methods from I18n
>
> ```
> I18n.t(:token) 
> I18n.l(Time.now)
> ```

So, you need to do:

```
<h2>I18n.t(:contest_page_title')</h2>
```

And, in your `locales/en.yml`, you will have:

```
en:
  contest_page_title: Free, open song contest
```

Since the `i18n` gem is also used in Rails, basic aspects of internationalization can also be inferred from [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)